# Non-zero Values of Data.Table Column

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to extract the non-zero values of a specific column `a` of my `data.table`. Here is an example

```
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(
    id = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
    a = sample(c(0,1), 6, replace=TRUE),
    b = 7:12,
    c = 13:18
)
col <- "a"
```

If `DT` is a `data.frame`, I can do

```
x <- DT[,col]       # I can do DT[,..col] to translate this line
x[x>0]              # here is where I am stuck
```

Since `DT` is a `data.table`, this code fails. The error message is: "i is invalid type (matrix)".

I tried `as.vector(x)` but without success.

Any hint appreciated. This seems to be a beginner question. However, searching SO and the introduction vignette for data.table did not turn up a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use `.SDcols` to specify the column

```
DT[DT[, .SD[[1]] > 0, .SDcols = col]]
```

---

or with `get`

```
DT[DT[ ,get(col) > 0]]

DT[get(col) > 0][[col]]
#[1] 1 1
```

---

Or another option is `[[`

```
DT[DT[[col]] > 0]
#  id a  b  c
#1:  a 1 11 17
#2:  c 1 12 18
```

Or to get only the column

```
DT[DT[[col]] >0][[col]]
#[1] 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter:

```
DT %>% filter(column_name > 0)
```